# how can i change text when pausing / resuming phaser game?

Tags: phaser-framework, pause, resume

I'm trying to toggle between 'Pause' and 'Resume' text when pausing and resuming, i tried the following in `create`:

```
gameState.playPauseText = this.add.text(660, 547, 'Pause', { fontFamily: 'Roboto Mono, monospace', fontSize: '20px',  fill: '#FFFFFF' });
```

then tried changing that inside a callback function:

```
gameState.playPauseArea.on('pointerdown', () => {
        if(!gameState.isPaused) {
            gameState.playPauseText.setText('Resume');
            game.loop.sleep();
            gameState.isPaused = true;

        }
        else {
            gameState.playPauseText.setText('Pause');
            game.loop.wake();
            gameState.isPaused = false;
           
        }
    });
```

then i tried same, but changed `.setText` to `.text =`. The best i got from all above is to change text to 'Resume' after 2 clicks, but never back to 'Pause'.

I also tried the following in `update`:

```
if(gameState.isPaused) {
        gameState.pauseText.setText('Resume')
        

    } else {
        gameState.pauseText.setText('Pause');
       
    }
```

that didn't do anything.

I also tried creating two separate texts and hiding one with `setVisible(false)` and tried all of the above toggling both 'Resume' and 'Pause' between `setVisible(true)` and `setVisible(false)`.

also nothing.

I use `.setText()` somewhere in my code, to change score text and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you are stopping the *game loop*, so nothing is going to be painted/updated any more. You could call the `game.loop.sleep()` with abit of delay, so that a `repaint`, will still be triggert.

```
...
setTimeout( () => game.loop.sleep(), 50);
...
```

Or with the Phaser [delayedCall](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Time.Clock.html#delayedCall__anchor) function:

```
...    
this.time.delayedCall(50, game.loop.sleep, null, game.loop);
...
```

**here a short demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {
   let text = this.add.text(30, 90, 'Click me to start');
   let pause = false;
   
   this.input.on('pointerdown', () => {
    if(!pause) {
            text.setText('Click me to Resume');
            setTimeout( _ => game.loop.sleep(), 50);
            pause = true;

        }
        else {
            text.setText('Click me to Pause');
            game.loop.wake();
            pause = false;
           
        }
   })
}

let game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```